# Create an object of random class in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection, polymorphism

I learned java and python in high school and I became very comfortable with python. I have recently started to learn kotlin, mainly for fun (the keyword for defining a function is `fun` so it has to be a fun language, right), but I have a little problem.

Let's suppose I have a hierarchy of classes for Chess pieces:

```kt
abstract class Piece {
    ...
}

class Rook : Piece() {
    ...
}

class Bishop : Piece() {
    ...
}
.
.
.
```

I am taking input from the user to generate the board, so if the user types `r`, I need to create a `Rook` object, if he types `b`, I need to create a `Bishop` etc.

In python, I'd probably use a dictionary that maps the input string to the corresponding **class**, so I can create an object of the correct type:

```py
class Piece:
    ...


class Rook(Piece):
    ...


class Bishop(Piece):
    ...
.
.
.


input_map = {
    'r': Rook,
    'b': Bishop,
    ...
}

s = input_map[input()]()  # use user input as key and create a piece of the correct type
```

I was really amazed by this pattern when I discovered it. In java, I had to use a switch case or a bunch of `if else if` to achieve the same result, which is not the end of the world, especially if I abstract it into a separate function, but it's not as nice as the python approach.

I want to do the same thing in kotlin, and I was wondering if there is a similar pattern for kotlin since it's a modern language like python (I know, I know, python isn't new, but I think it's very modern). I tried to look online, but it seems like I can't store a class (class, not an object) in a variable or a map like I can in python.

Am I wrong about it? Can I use a similar pattern in kotlin or do I have to fall back to the `when` statement (or expression)?

If I am not mistaken, a similar pattern could be achieved in java using reflection. I never got to learn reflection in java deeply, but I know it's a way to use classes dynamically, what I can do for free in python. I also heard that in java, reflection should be used as a last resort because it's inefficient and it's considered "black magic" if you understand my meaning. Does it mean that I need to use reflection to achieve that result in kotlin? And if so, is it recommended to use reflection in kotlin, and is it efficient?

I'd like to know how I can approach this problem, and I accept multiple answers and additional solutions I didn't come up with. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done without reflection.

You can map the input characters to the constructors:

```
val pieceConstructorsByKeyChar = mapOf(
    'r' to ::Rook,
    'b' to ::Bishop,
    // etc.
)
```

Getting values from a map gives you a nullable, since it's possible the key you supply isn't in the map. Maybe this is fine, if when you use this you might be passing a character the player typed that might not be supported. Then you would probably handle `null` by telling the player to try again:

```
val piece: Piece? = pieceConstructorsByKeyChar[keyPressed]?.invoke()
```

Or if you do the look-up after you've already checked that it's a valid key-stroke, you can use `!!` safely:

```
val piece: Piece = pieceConstructorsByKeyChar[keyPressed]!!()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use similiar approach with Kotlin. Kotlin has many features and supports reflection. Let me write an example about your problem.

Firstly create your classes that will be generate by user input.

```
abstract class Piece

class Rook : Piece()
class Bishop : Piece()
```

Create your class map

```
val inputMap = mapOf(
        "r" to Rook::class.java,
        "b" to Bishop::class.java
)
```

Create an instance what you want using `newInstance` function. If your input map doesn't contains key you gave then it will return `null`.

```
    val rook = inputMap["r"]?.newInstance()
    val bishop = inputMap["b"]?.newInstance()
    
    // null
    val king = inputMap["k"]?.newInstance()
```

Also you can write your custom extensions to create new objects.

```
    fun <T> Map<String, Class<out T>>.newInstance(key: String) = this[key]?.newInstance()

    // Create an instance with extension function
    inputMap.newInstance("r")
```

Comment: Cool. I am new to kotlin. In python, this is a pythonic solution. Would you consider this solution in kotlin a good practice? I heard people usually don’t like reflection in java and I don’t know if it applies to kotlin. Also, your solution is specific to kotlin for jvm if I am not mistaken. Is it the best bet, or there is a more general solution?

Comment: I think it depends your architecture and what do you want. Kotlin can work perfectly with Java so it can be use Java reflection API also it provides own reflection api too. Both way work perfectly without cause any problem.

Comment: @ShaiAvr Those are very wise questions!  As you say, what's good practice in one language many not be so in another, and there may be more idiomatic alternatives.  I see a lot of questions about reflection from people used to dynamic languages, when there are often non-reflective solutions which are more robust, efficient, safe, widely-supported, and/or concise.  This answer is clear, detailed, and nicely explained — but I think Tenfour04's rather illustrates my point!  (Sorry, Ekrem :-)